# We have a rather large django site running at awful performance and we need help finding the cause

Tags: python, django, performance

We have a rather large Django site and its running very slow (>3000ms per page load).

Something is choking performance but we have no idea what.

We have only 10 queries executing in 8ms from MySQL. If we disable all css+javascript it still takes >3000ms to load.

```
django-debug-toolbar:
User CPU time   264.384 msec
System CPU time 104.791 msec
Total CPU time  369.175 msec
Elapsed time    2621.822 msec
```

We tried `runprofileserver` from `django-extensions` and got some profiledata:

https://portal.bitcasa.com/send/f19b6dd7bd2bd724737ce42a6e4c342b10349a73214877227628939a5f5331ea/37359a48a7f5e3422778be654e9dd74896b1d6c25249b327e2f5d3bd1966ddbe

When i try to decipher the profiling data i come to the conclusion that rendered_content via render (template rendering?) is why its slow, problem is that if we try disable parts of the base template it doesnt make any difference.

Can someone please try help us?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a good question for Stack Overflow, see the [FAQ]. A profile dump of your specific site is simply not general enough to be helpful to others, nor is it specific enough for us to help you. For this kind of problem, you probably are going to have to find yourself a consultant.

Comment: I have the same problem also. I am wondering what was causing this high time lapse.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use some profiling tool like Tracelytics or New Relic.

It is hard to tell, but some common causes could be:

- Miscommunication with caching layer
- Misuse of queries (large queries, add indexes, use `select_related` and `prefetch_related`)
- Using django-debug-toolbar itself makes things much slower. Make sure you have DEBUG=False